# Make Status bar Translucent on pre lollipop devices(kit-kat) while being compatible with jelly bean

Tags: java, android, xml

Making an Android application with `Minimum sdk version` `jelly bean`.
I want to make status bar translucent there are many ways to make status bar translucent on kitkat devices. On applying some of them error says jelly bean does not support this type of theme and then app would not compile. (I don't even want or think for making status bar translucent in jelly bean).I just want application to compatible with jelly bean and having status bar translucent in Kit-Kat.
Ideas please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present there are 3 types of status bar in Android. TYPE 1 : Status Bar in Pre-Kitkat devices. TYPE 2 : Status Bar in Kitkat devices which is having Translucent Property which can merge The content of our application with content of status bar. TYPE 3 : Status bar after Lollipop which is Translucent and also we can set color of status bar by adding one line on Styles.xml. Now, to have different properties of different status bars in different devices we have to define different Style.xml file for each api like v16 , v19, v21.